# Object scope on methods

Tags: javascript, object, methods, scope

let's say I code:

```
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click",() => console.log(btn.textContent));
```

Can somebody explain why the btn variable, that is storing a reference to a DOM node, can be accessed inside of the callback function passed to the addEventListener method? I thought that it was out of scope but I saw that the code runs without problems.

I'm new to JS so please don't be rude ahaha.

Comment: The [MDN article on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) may be useful to help understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Any code that appears in a scope (*inner*) (be it defined by a function, block, etc) has access to any variable in the scope (*outer*) where the *inner* scope was created unless that variable is [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 0):

Because your variable is created in the global scope. [There more information.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: but if the code I have written was bounded into a function, meaning that the btn variable is a local one, it still works